# Elasticsearch - Query on array for matching multiple objects in the array

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to write a query that will match a document with a nested object that is an array of objects. Example :

```
{"ListName" : "List 1", "Fruits": [ { "name" : "Apple"}, {"name": "Orange"}, {"name" : "banana"} ] }
```

I would like to write a query were I get the document above based on the names inside the Fruits array, e.g. Apple and Orange.

What I currently have matches names with both Apple and Orange in the same name field rather than each object.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Fruits",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "Fruits.name": "Apple"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "Fruits.name": "Orange"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make two different `nested` queries in a `bool/must` query instead, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Fruits",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "Fruits.name": "Apple"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Fruits",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "Fruits.name": "Orange"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```